# htaccess remove multiple char at end of string

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, environment-variables

As an example, how can i remove the char "&" at the end of the string?

```
RewriteCond &&&&fddfdf&&& ^&*(.*)&*$
RewriteRule .* - [E=test:%1,NE]
```

Variable "test" seems to return "fddfdf&&&" instead of the expected output of "fddfdf",
any ideas whats wrong with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(.*)` is capturing the `&` too.  The `&*$` at the end does not prevent this; the regex is still satisfied because it matches the lack of `&`.  Use `(.*?)` to make the regex reluctant.  It will match up to the first `&`.

All together:

```
RewriteCond &&&&fddfdf&&& ^&*(.*?)&*$
```